# Move to next view controller, i am using storyboard

Tags: ios

[image]

Here is my code

```
RadarViewController *wc = [[RadarViewController alloc]
                                initWithNibName:@"RadarViewController"
                                bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:wc animated:YES];
```

Here is the error comes after crashing the app.

```
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
 2015-10-14 12:25:02.596 Quick man help[890:60170] *** Terminating    app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/brainpulse/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0FD1A490-11AF-468D-96D3-71F37DDD8552/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/35FDBB50-E294-458B-B367-A57E3FC0B594/Quick man help.app> (loaded)' with name 'RadarViewController''
```

Comment: Is your RadarViewController in storyboard ?

Comment: yes it is in my storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Your Xcode can not find a xib with name "RadarViewController" because you are using storyboard ....

You need to create instance of RadarViewController from storyboard like

```
UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
radarVC = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"radarVCID"];
```

You need to set radarVCID as storyboardID of RadarViewController in your storyboard

Comment: i already did it, please find my screen shot of radarviewcontroller.

Comment: RadarViewController *wc = [[RadarViewController alloc]
                                initWithNibName:@"RadarViewController"
                                bundle:nil]; This code you also need to change

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below:

1. Select your `RadarViewController` in storyboard
2. In Identity Inspector, give `RadarViewController` identifier in `Storyboard ID`. for example "capture" as you can see in screenshot

[image]

Now write something like below:

```
   RadarViewController *obj  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"youridentifier"];//youridentifier =capture as per screenshot. You can give whatever identifier to  `RadarViewController`

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i already did it  same like your capture image , again app crash and give the error i mentioned.

Comment: Does RadarViewController has any XIB in your project ? because your error is saying "Could not load NIB in bundle"

Comment: Have you used NavigationController ?

Comment: i am not create any xib in my project, i create a view controller from the interface builder and assign a class name   RadarViewController .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that not all connections as parts of the archive has been already loaded from the storyboard at the moment you call `initWithNibName` as same as `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.
I suggest you to instatiate your view controller in `viewDidLoad`.
If it won't help, try to look if your storyboard is correct. To achieve this open it as a source code and look at opening/closing tags
[image]

After all of that, delete you view controller and re-add.Don't forget to create a copy of your storyboard before performing all of this.